# Is it possible to add rich textbox with image via rest?

Tags: rest-api, rest, remote-objects

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to add text with image to rich text area field by rest.

How should be done and how would i have to make such a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Here are the two link you can use either one of it based on your requirement.
Let me know in case you need more information

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/converting-a-rich-text-area-fields-image-for-api-upload

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002745&language=en_US

Comment: Does base64 encoded image counts against 13k character limit?

Comment: Yes it is there are multiple ways to overcome from this limit based on type of API